# Problems with Lubuntu 17.04

Tags: lubuntu, 17.04

A few months ago, I upgraded to Lubuntu 17.04 from a bug-ridden earlier release--hoping for a release without bugs. But, I still found the following problems:

1. From the System Tools --> Software menu, I cannot install other software because I don't have permission to do so. Why?
2. When Lubuntu tells me I have updates, I cannot install them. They are downloaded but not installed for some reason. (I no longer get a message saying that my computer is up-to-date. And, updates are backing up; more and more are waiting to be installed.

Comment: Do you have 'sudo' rights in your current account?  Please open a terminal and enter the command `sudo apt update` and append the output of that command to your question.

Comment: rogerc@rogerc-ThinkPad-H:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease [78.6 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease [78.6 kB]    
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease [72.2 kB] 
Fetched 229 kB in 0s (242 kB/s)                                                
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
71 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

Comment: Ok - presumably you could get your computer up to date with `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: "sudo apt upgrade" worked.  But, after i tried it, and got it to work, I tried to install updates normally -- following a system notification of the availability of updates -- and the updates would not download or install?

Comment: If you open a terminal, and enter the command `gnome-software` the "normal" software program should appear.  Starting it in this method may allow error messages to appear in the terminal window if the program does not work as it is supposed to.  If there are such messages, could you copy them and paste them into your question (not into a comment!)